# Files are damaged after copying

Tags: media

One of my relatives gave me her laptob and asked me to change the windows,(lenovo ideapad Z600).

First I made a backup of all data on the computer to a external hard, then I wiped everything including partions and I changed the format of the hard drive.

After I finished installing windows I restored my backup from my external hard, some of files (specially the files that were copied from a camera) were damaged and some of them were right (specially the files that were downloaded from internet).

Images and videos (family files) are damaged,and I'm getting nervous about it!

Still I've got damaged data, they are like 50GB but half of them are not opening.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Are the files on the external disk OK? How did you perform the backup?

Comment: Lenovo Ideapad is not a version of Windows. What Windows was on the laptop? What Windows version did you change to? How did you perform this window(s) change? Was the external hard drive healthy before? What tool did you use to wipe the drive?

Comment: Are they **damaged** or simply not opening on the reinstalled windows? In the last case you simply did not yet install a program which understands the required file format.

Comment: @Hennes Good point! I didn't think of that. That could be why half of them (assuming "data" means files) are "opening" (the other half is not opening). Let's hope that this is the case. Being able to open a file is not the same thing as having damaged data. Sometimes even damaged data can be open and interpreted, sometimes data is "damaged" intentionally even (e.g. data bending or glitch art) and still usable.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to try using **Recuva** to restore what can be restored. Make sure not to install it on the same disk. There is a portable version available, and I recommend using that. As usual, don't save anything to the damaged disk. The files you recover should be saved to a third disk drive. *You could use a separate partition on the same disk, but it must have been created before the incident.*

[image: recuva]

You can find *(the portable version of)* the program here: https://www.piriform.com/recuva/builds

*Also, act fast!* Time is of the essence! The more you wait the slimmer are the chances that you will recover much, if anything at all. Even if you are not using the damaged disk! The system can still see it and use it, or even decide to do a `chkdsk` on it. It will need to be write-protected to ensure that no date is touched on it. The way to ensure that is by unmounting it from the operating system, or by disconnecting it from the computer until you are ready to work on recovery.

There is also a program called **TestDisk**. It can be used to restore complete disk partitions. *(I managed to recover two lost NTFS partitions that I had removed by accident once.)* If you have not formatted the disk drive of the laptop and installed Windows on it, you might recover more, if not the entire data set using this program. But if you have already done so, then it is too late to use this program.

[image: testdisk]

You can find this program here: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

*This program only exists as a portable version, there is no installer. It is also possible obtain a LiveCD image. Booting from the the LiveCD is probably the best way to use it.*

For future reference: don't use a bad disk drive to store your backup. Also, use a proper backup program to create a full disk image, or a file backup. The benefit of using a proper backup program is that it can check and verify the integrity of the backup file. Also, if possible, create a secondary backup for a peace of mind. Two is better than one.

Comment: One problem with making backup images is that some poorly made software will not bother adding some redundancy onto the image and instead just not let you restore at all if checksum fails.

Comment: Supposedly safe backup that can't be restored... interesting. Any software in particular? That sounds more like a problem with that particular software, not with disk image backup per se.

Comment: I know I once used Samsung Kies to make a full backup of all data objects on my phone, do that I could do a factory reset safely. Later on, it offered to only restore messages, contacts, and pictures. More than half of object types were not recoverable due to some limitation in Kies software and Android itself. This was by design however, not due to a damaged backup. I never used this sorry excuse for a backup program again! I mean why even offer to backup objects that are known upfront that they can't be restored later on... devious crapware.

Comment: If a backup restore fails completely due to a checksum mismatch then it is for a good reason. This is why you should verify integrity after making the backup, and then do it regularly once it is created to make sure it is intact. Acronis TIB can do this on a schedule. You don't want to restore even a partially corrupted backup, or not even get a warning about it. You will be sorry later on.

Comment: Also, if you can afford extra storage space, don't use compression! You will have a quicker backup process, and you have better chance of restoring corrupted backups. Partially corrupted and uncompressed backups can be recovered by reading and analyzing the raw data. Even more so for disk image backups. Actually! One technique commonly used in data recovery, such as the one described by the author in this question, is to create a disk image backup of the **damaged** (corrupted) disk. It's easier to work on and there is no fear for degradation because you can write-protect the file and reuse it

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a long shot, but try using [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on the external hard drive. PhotoRec is a free file recovery utility that should work well for your purposes. It can't recover all kinds of files, but from what I can tell it should be able to recover the files you need (there's a complete list of recoverable files on the page linked above).  It may be a bit complicated to use (TUI, text interface without being quite command-line), but it shouldn't be too hard to figure it out once you first run it.